# How to control which user control to load in a way that allows user control events to fire

Tags: asp.net, events, user-controls, viewstate

I dynamically load one of many user controls based on which tab the user clicks. I store the selected tab index in view state. The user control has a checkbox on it that fires an OnChanged event. My problem is that if I load the user control in Page_Load, the checkbox event doesn't fire because the control didn't get created in time. If I load the user control in Page_Init, the page doesn't know which user control to load I believe because the ViewState isn't loaded yet. How can I store which user control to load AND get the events on the user control to fire?

Comment: I'll just add that you can get the checkbox event to fire if you load it dynamically in Page_Load of the containing page/control.  If it is not firing then likely something else is going wrong.  The most common problem I've seen that creates this problem is not setting the id of the checkbox to the same id everytime you initialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best strategy I've found has been to create all the controls in the Page_Init event, and set their `Visible` property to false (in Page_Load in your case) if they aren't supposed to be present on the rendered page.

**Edit**

Another option is to determine which controls to load based on some other criterion (besides ViewState). For example, if you make the current tab one of your query string parameters, that data will be available on the request during Page_Init.

Comment: I don't think that's an option for me. The user controls are very large and, because of performance, I made it so only one is loaded at a time. Do you know of any other strategies?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, to response to your edit, I'm loading the control on postback, so to get the tab index into the query string, I'd have to have the page redirect to itself. Since performance is an issue, I don't think I can afford another page lifecycle. I was thinking of using a hidden form field instead. Do you see any problems with this or do you have any other options?

Comment: @adam0101: If you don't need to persist other page data when someone clicks a tab, you could simply make the tab button a link rather than a postback button. If you need to persist viewstate for other page items, though, there are still a variety of options. A hidden field will probably work as well as anything. BTW, I highly recommend this article (http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) to help avoid some of the performance pitfalls inherent in WebForms.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: After evaluating a few options, I think I'm going to go with your first suggestion and just show and hide the controls as needed. I'll just add an additional step of binding the datasources of any hidden controls to "Nothing" to keep the viewstate size under control. Thanks.

Comment: You bet. Good luck. And be sure to read that article for other strategies for keeping ViewState under control, too.  Cheers.